# Ruby writing zip file works on Mac but not on windows / How to recieve zip file in Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, zip, net-http

actually i'm writing a ruby script which accesses an API based on HTTP-POST calls.
The API returns a zip file containing textdocuments when i call it with specific POST-Parameters. At the moment i'm doing that with the Net::HTTP Package.

Now my problem:
It seems to return the zip-file as a string as far as i know. I can see "PK" (which i suppose is part of the PK-Header of zip-files) and the text from the documents.

And the Content-Type Header is telling me "application/x-zip-compressed; name="somename.zip"".

When i save the zip file like so:

```
result = comodo.get_cert("<somenumber>")
puts result['Content-Type']
puts result.inspect
puts result.body

File.open("test.zip", "w") do |file|
    file.write result.body
end
```

I can unzip it on my macbook without further problems. But when i run the same code on my Win10 PC it tells me that the file is corrupt or not a ZIP-file.

Has it something to do with the encoding? Can i change it, so it's working on both?
Or is it a complete wrong approach on how to recieve a zip-file from a POST-request?

PS:
My ruby-version on Mac:

```
ruby 2.2.3p173
```

My ruby-version on Windows:

```
ruby 2.2.4p230
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the way Windows handles line endings (`\r\n` for Windows, whereas OS X and other Unix based operating systems use just `\n`).  When using `File.open`, using the mode of just `w` makes the file subject to line ending changes, so any occurrences of byte 0x0A (or `\n`) are converted into bytes 0x0D 0x0A (or `\r\n`), which effectively breaks the zip.

When opening the file for write, use the mode `wb` instead, as this will suppress any line ending changes.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks! Just as you posted the solution i found it out myself..

So much trouble because of one missing 'b' :/

Thank you very much!

**The solution (see [Ben Y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296386/3751188)):**

```
result = comodo.get_cert("<somenumber>")
puts result['Content-Type']
puts result.inspect
puts result.body

File.open("test.zip", "wb") do |file|
    file.write result.body
end
```